# Where can I get Fonts for Adobe InDesign CS5 software? I do not have Creative Cloud

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, mac

I have an older mac pro 1.1 and Adobe Indesign CS5 software that is about 10 years old. I would like to add some new fonts to use.  Is that possible? & where would I purchase them?  I do not have a Creative Cloud account.  Thanks! Chris

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There are many websites offering paid and free fonts.  You can do a web search to find them.  All you need to do is download and install them.  InDesign can use any fonts installed on your computer.

Comment: Some reputable websites: myfonts.com (for paid fonts). fonts.google.com (for free fonts). I have no affiliation with these websites.

Answer (score 1):

This question Is in reality several questions.

**First answer.**

1. Get a creative cloud for a month or two and get some fonts. I think you are not limited to the number of fonts you can download.
2. A good option is Google Fonts, where you can download the fonts "free of charge".
3. There are a lot of websites where you can buy individual fonts. Simply google them.

**The second answer** is a question. To use for what?

A lot of websites allow you to download and use fonts for personal use. The invitation to your daughter's birthday party, things like that. Most websites you find when searching "free font" will fall into that category.

You need to define the usage, then see if **the license you are getting and accepting** matches. The golden rule is that you are not allowed to redistribute them.